# Writing back to a github hosted comma seperated value (csv) file from a heroku deployed app

Tags: python, pandas, csv, flask, heroku

Actually, I'm creating a flask app which just takes the name as input and writes it into a csv file in different rows every time. The thing works good locally but I've it hosted on Heroku which seems to work perfectly but isn't. When I clone the Heroku app repository using Heroku commandline using `heroku git:clone -a <app-name>` the csv file I get is not updated. I tried looking to various sources which can help me in this. The best one I found was to use the github hosted csv file. I just succeed in reading that file using pandas by :

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parthpandyappp/Saturday-Talks/main/registered.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False)
```

Now, I want help for appending the name and writing back to the github hosted csv file. I looked for it in various places but didn't find one.

Comment: `git` is a version control system. It is something where you store code, logic, functionality of your project. It is not something where you store data. For that you should use a database server.  
Heroku uses an [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku#ephemeral-disk) which means anything that is written during runtime is lost on the next start. You need to rely on a proper database. Instead of creating an ugly workaround of commiting changes to a git which you then retrieve from you should use a proper database straight away.

Comment: Yes, today itself I discovered the ephemeral behaviour regarding file system. But many people have used this method as it's more convenient and handy to use.